Reference for basic multicategory theory
A multicategory (or coloured operad, if you like) is a category where instead of (only) morphisms between objects we have multimorphisms from finite lists of objects to (single) objects.
There may be further bells and whistles, e.g. a symmetric group action.
Morally, they are monoidal categories where we know what the morphisms out of monoidal products are supposed to be but do not know (or do not care) what morphisms into monoidal products are.
(Famously, the tensor product of modules is defined in this way: multilinear maps are conceptually prior!)
Question.
What are some textbook-style references for basic multicategory theory?
Is there an equivalent of Mac Lane's Categories for the working mathematician?
For example, I would like to see precise definitions, statements, and proofs for the following:

Given a monoidal category, we can define the "underlying" multicategory to have as its multimorphisms $[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to Y$ the morphisms $( \cdots (X_1 \otimes X_2) \otimes \cdots ) \otimes X_n \to Y$; lax monoidal functors then give rise to multicategory functors in the obvious way, and so on.

Given objects $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ in a multicategory, a monoidal representation is an object $A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n$ and a multimorphism $\eta : [A_1, \ldots, A_n] \to A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n$ such that, for every multimorphism $f : [X, \ldots, A_1, \ldots, A_n, Y, \ldots] \to Z$, there is a unique multimorphism $[X, \ldots, A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n, Y, \ldots] \to Z$ such that precomposing $\eta$ yields $f$.
(This what Hermida calls strongly universal.)

If every pair of objects in a multicategory has a monoidal representation, then every finite list of positive length has a monoidal representation.

If every finite list of objects in a multicategory has a monoidal representation – i.e. if the multicategory is representable – then it is equivalent to the "underlying" multicategory of a monoidal category.

Likewise for symmetric (resp. braided) monoidal categories and symmetric (resp. braided) multicategories.

Given a closed category, we can define the "underlying" multicategory to have as its multimorphisms $[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to Y$ the morphisms $X_1 \to X_2 \multimap (\cdots \multimap (X_n \multimap Y) \cdots)$; closed functors then give rise to multicategory functors, and so on.

Given objects $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and $B$ in a multicategory, an internal hom representation is an object $[A_1, \ldots, A_n] \multimap B$ and a multimorphism $\epsilon : [A_1, \ldots, A_n, [A_1, \ldots, A_n] \multimap B] \to B$ such that, for every multimorphism $f : [A_1, \ldots, A_n, Y, \ldots] \to B$, there is a unique multimorphism $[Y, \ldots] \to [A_1, \ldots, A_n] \multimap B$ such that postcomposing $\epsilon$ yields $f$.
(We could define a two-sided version of this, but since it does not appear in Manzyuk's paper, I assume it is not necessary.)

If every $A$ and $B$ has an internal hom representation, then every $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and $B$ has an internal hom representation.

If, in addition, the empty list has a monoidal representation, then the multicategory is equivalent to the "underlying" multicategory of a closed category.

Possible definitions of colimits in a multicategory, and more generally universal objects characterised by outgoing morphisms.
(I presume there is no controversy about the correct definition of universal objects characterised by incoming multimorphisms, but unfortunately multicategory theory does not have arrow-reversing duality...)

The definitions of adjunction between multicategories, and some translation of the fact that in a monoidal adjunction the left adjoint is strong monoidal.

Given a monad on a multicategory, we can form Kleisli and Eilenberg–Moore multicategories of algebras.
The Kleisli multicategory is representable if the base is, and the Eilenberg–Moore multicategory is representable under some additional hypotheses regarding reflexive coequalisers.



There was quite a bit in Leinster's Higher Operads, Higher Categories: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049

You could look at https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.0082

I don't believe the reference you are looking for currently exists. I say this because I also wanted such a reference and spent time looking for one. I can give references for most of the points you ask about in isolation (though I suspect you will already be familiar with most if not all of them), but there is no single reference for all of them. I'm sure I have overlooked some references, as the literature is not very well connected; I would also be interested in references that fill in these gaps.
As mentioned in the comments, Leinster's Higher Operads, Higher Categories is probably the best textbook reference for multicategories. However, its intention is not to be a general reference for multicategory theory and, as such, there are many topics it does not cover, or mentions only briefly.
For (1 – 4), I think the best reference is still Hermida's paper Representable Multicategories, with a slightly different perspective offered in From coherent structures to universal properties. Leinster's book also covers this topic, but in less detail.
For (5), the theory of representability for symmetric multicategories is covered in §3 of Weber's Free products of higher operad algebras. I don't know of a reference in the setting of braided multicategories; I suspect there is not one.
For (6 – 9), there are three relevant references that come to mind. One is Manzyuk's paper Closed categories vs. closed multicategories, as you mention. Another is Weber's paper mentioned above, which also treated the closed case. A third is §6 of Bourke and Lack's paper Skew monoidal categories and skew multicategories, which works in additional generality, but offers an abstract perspective on the correspondence (tangential, but perhaps also of interest is Uustalu–Veltri–Zeilberger's Eilenberg-Kelly Reloaded).
Regarding:

(We could define a two-sided version of this, but since it does not appear in Manzyuk's paper, I assume it is not necessary.)

Every closed category induces both a left-closed multicategory (by defining multimorphisms $A_1, \ldots, A_n \to B$ as morphisms $A_n \to [A_{n - 1}, \ldots, [A_1, B] \ldots ]$) and a right-closed multicategories (by defining multimorphisms $A_1, \ldots, A_n \to B$ as morphisms $A_1 \to [A_2, \ldots, [A_n, B] \ldots ]$). The induced left-closed multicategory is the reverse of the induced right-closed multicategory.
I do not believe there is a reference for (10) at all, as I spent some time looking for one previously. There are a number of subtleties in isolating the appropriate notion of "couniversal" concepts for multicategories. The references I think are most relevant are Hermida's Fibrations and Yoneda structure for multicategories and §2 of Shulman's The 2-Chu-Dialectica construction and the polycategory of multivariable adjunctions. As you say, universal concepts generalise to multicategories in an evident way, although I also do not know of an explicit reference.
For (11), adjunctions between multicategories are briefly considered in §6.3 of Hermida's Representable Multicategories. However, I do not know of a reference for their interaction with representability; again, I had looked for such a reference without success.
There are a few relevant references for (12). One is §3.4 of Weber's Free Products of Higher Operad Algebras. Another is §3 of Aguiar–Haim–Lopez Franco's Monads on higher monoidal categories. These references do not mention Kleisli, but this is obviously the simpler of the two cases (e.g. as described in Seal's Tensors, monads and actions, albeit not in the setting of multicategories).

I am surprised that colimits have not been worked out yet... ah well. Perhaps someday, someone will work it out and write Multicategories for the working mathematician and I will have to change the accepted answer!

Re: left- vs right- vs bi-closed multicategories, these were considered in Lambek's original paper on multicategories "Deductive systems and categories 2" (https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0079385), though he did not consider non-monoidal closed categories there. Note that the notion of non-monoidal closed category does not have a left/right bias: assuming the presence of a unit object I, both left-closed multicategories and right-closed multicategories give rise to closed categories, and more generally (without assuming I) they induce prounital closed categories (https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.03809).

@NoamZeilberger: thanks, I was conflating with the monoidal situation. I've updated that remark.

@ZhenLin Regarding colimits (10), there's a bit more in my paper LNL polycategories and doctrines of linear logic, the last couple of pages of section 2.  It's written for the more general case of LNL polycategories, but it can be specialized to ordinary (symmetric) multicategories, as discussed at the end under "restricted universal properties".
